# How can minted (or something similar) work with automatic alignment of code?

Tags: listings, alignment, minted, code

I typeset Lisp code in a proportional typeface, and it relies on alignment. An example of the typesetting can be seen here:

[image: aligned Racket code in a proportional typeface]

If I ignore font selection, it was typeset using this code:

```
\begin{tabbing}
    (begin \= (define (a 1)) \\
           \> (list \= a \\
           \>       \> 2 \\
           \>       \> 3))
\end{tabbing}
```

Using normal spaces to align is not viable because I don't know how much indentation is needed, and it may be a fractional amount of spaces. I use the environment `tabbing` because it has the simplest effective way to align text.

I would like to have the code syntactically highlighted. So far, I have been doing manual highlighting, but it is time-consuming and more difficult than how it should be IMO because tabstops cancel highlighting going over them.

Is there a way to use a code highlighter like minted with alignment like with `tabbing` or [elastic tabstops](https://nickgravgaard.com/elastic-tabstops/)?

Comment: Could you include some code we can copy/paste/trial solutions with please?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz There is no answer, so it doesn't answer my question. But that is about aligning, and this is about aligning and automatic highlighting at the same time. What is described in that question works with manual highlighting (although suboptimally), and, in this question, I would like to know how to highlight automatically.

Comment: @JamesT What exactly do you mean? Do you want the code used to typeset the example image?

Comment: Yeah the code used to typeset the image, it means we do not need to guess or create a test document ourselves

Comment: You already mentioned highlighting in your previous question, so this one is essentially the same. The wording of the automatic comment is indeed a bit unfortunate for unanswered questions by the same person, but these do tend to get closed as duplicates. Hopefully someone will answer your previous question, which would then also answer this one.